# Force mysql to use index a certain way

Tags: mysql

I've found that when running queries against our MySQL DB (5.5.27) that when the optimizer chooses to use to use the index as range it responds quickly, but when it chooses ref_or_null it takes significantly longer.

Is there any way to force an index to always use range?

Comment: How are you getting it to change between `range` and `ref_or_null` now?  Are you sure that what you're doing for that isn't causing the slow down?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the optimizer is not using the indexes properly, you can try to use index hints.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1 USE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index)
> WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
> ```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html)